# Source code of the function `grDevices:::C_col2rgb`?

Tags: r, graphics, rgl

How can I find the source C code of the function `grDevices:::C_col2rgb`?

I've been led to this function after benchmarking (using R pkg profvis) some RGL functions, namely `rgl:::rgl.quads` and functions called therein. The corresponding R function that wraps `C_col2rgb` is `col2rgb` from grDevices. I'm interested in looking at the source of `C_col2rgb` to see whether I could make a faster version.

And, in general, when you encounter a C function being used in R code, is there an expedite way of finding its source code?

Many thanks!

[image: benchmark]

Comment: Check out [`wch/r-source` on GitHub](https://github.com/wch/r-source) (my favorite R source code mirror). In particular, you want [`r-source/src/library/grDevices/src/colors.c`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/4ce4b479d4e32ccc38f7250fc6090852fb790334/src/library/grDevices/src/colors.c#L545)

Comment: Thank you @duckmayr. But I am a bit confused, is `col2rgb` the same as `C_col2rgb`?

Comment: Yes. Will add a full answer with explanation in a moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally when you want to view the source code of an R function, you can just type its name in the console and press enter. However, when that function is written in another language, such as C, and exposed to R, you will just eventually see (something like)

```
.Call(C_col2rgb, col, alpha)
```

where R calls the compiled code. To see the source code of such functions, you actually have to look at the package source code. The function you are talking about is in the `grDevices` package, which is part of what is often called "base R" (not (necessarily) to be confused with the R package `base`) -- the package ships with all R installations.

There is an R source code mirror on GitHub at https://github.com/wch/r-source that I like to consult if I need to look at R's source code. The code for the `grDevices` package is there at https://github.com/wch/r-source/tree/trunk/src/library/grDevices.

As I mentioned in the comments, you can find the code for `C_col2rgb()` at [`r-source/src/library/grDevices/src/colors.c`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/4ce4b479d4e32ccc38f7250fc6090852fb790334/src/library/grDevices/src/colors.c#L545). However, there it looks like it's just called `col2rgb()`. Is it really the same?

**Yes**. If you consult [Writing R Extensions, Section 1.5.4](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#useDynLib), you see that

> A NAMESPACE file can contain one or more useDynLib directives which allows shared objects that need to be loaded.... Using argument .fixes allows an automatic prefix to be added to the registered symbols, which can be useful when working with an existing package. For example, package KernSmooth has
>
> useDynLib(KernSmooth, .registration = TRUE, .fixes = "F_")
>
> which makes the R variables corresponding to the Fortran symbols F_bkde and so on, and so avoid clashes with R code in the namespace.

We can see in the [`NAMESPACE` file for `grDevices`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/4ce4b479d4e32ccc38f7250fc6090852fb790334/src/library/grDevices/NAMESPACE#L1)

```
useDynLib(grDevices, .registration = TRUE, .fixes = "C_")
```

So, the C functions that are made available from this package will *all* be prefixed with `C_` even though they aren't in the C source code. This lets you call both the R and the C functions `col2rgb` without causing any problems.

Comment: Terrific! Thank you so much.

Comment: I'd also mention the article by Uwe Ligges on p 43 in http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2006-4.pdf for a general discussion of how to figure out where to look.  It's a bit old, but still quite relevant.